# Regex: Search using (anchor string + expression). but extract only the expression

Tags: python, regex

Hi i have been using a command line tool which when executes returns some strings. i only want some part of it

```
'Deskew 1.20 (2016-09-01) by Marek Mauder x64\r\n
 http://galfar.vevb.net/deskew/\r\nLoad input file - time taken: 192,956 
 us\r\n
 Preparing input image (1514538.png) ...\r\nCalculating skew 
 angle...\r\nSkew detection - time taken: 2,854,167 us\r\nSkew angle found: 
 -0.50\r\nSkipping deskewing step, skew angle lower than threshold of 
 80.00\r\nSave output file - time taken: 68,184 us\r\nDone!\r\n'
```

For the experiment i am doing, performance is a factor of most importance. I only want to search for

```
 Skew angle found: -0.50
```

for that i used this expression `(Skew angle found: [-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+$)`
But the thing is what i actually need is the signed float part of it. But when i use only the `[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+$` expression, it also returns other numbers in the whole string. I know one way could be to search first and then extract the float only in that string. But that doesn't seem to be the most optimal way. Is there any way (Regex) with which i can pinpoint the Skew angle found location and only extract the float. Because that way i am hoping i can compile the regex and extract faster.

Please suggest

Comment: It sounds like you want a *lookbehind*. Or just put the capturing parentheses around the bit you want, not the whole pattern. See e.g. https://regex101.com/r/paeLgK/1

Comment: Just tested in regex101 to match the float: (-\d.\d+)

https://i.imgur.com/1cCWfNT.png

Comment: @jonrsharpe That works. Answer it as a question as you responded first :)

Comment: @F.Leone thanks. but the number can also be positive and can have something like this too. "23.4" check the answer above. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `re.search()` function:

```
import re

text = '''Deskew 1.20 (2016-09-01) by Marek Mauder x64\r\n
 http://galfar.vevb.net/deskew/\r\nLoad input file - time taken: 192,956
 us\r\n
 Preparing input image (1514538.png) ...\r\nCalculating skew
 angle...\r\nSkew detection - time taken: 2,854,167 us\r\nSkew angle found:
 -0.50\r\nSkipping deskewing step, skew angle lower than threshold of
 80.00\r\nSave output file - time taken: 68,184 us\r\nDone!\r\n'''

skew_angle = re.search(r'Skew angle found:\s*(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)', text).group(1)
print(skew_angle)
```

The output:

```
-0.50
```

Comment: @F.Leone your solution only works on number that are negative, have one integer digit and have multiple digits after the dot.